# Cosa significa "incovonare"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Tobia e i suoi mi trattarono come un malato, ma solo per un giorno, l’indomani Tobia mi rimise sotto e arrivato a scuro mi sembrava di non aver mai lavorata una giornata come quella. Mi fece bene. Un po’ come fa bene, quando hai lavorato tutta notte nella guazza a **incovonare**, non andartene a dormire ma invece rimetterti a tagliare al rosso del sole.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "incovonare"? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo in nessun dizionario. Ho visto però che appare anche nel racconto [*Alla Langa*](http://www.einaudi.it/libri/libro/beppe-fenoglio/l-affare-dell-anima-e-altri-racconti/978880638059) di Beppe Fenoglio:

> Quelli del Muraglione, che in luglio
>   avevano resistito a **incovonare** il grano
>   da soli, vennero con aria di trionfatori
>   sul campo di Elia, anche a costo di
>   preterire il lavoro suo.

Comment: Formare covoni.

Comment: «Incovonare» è un verbo parasintetico, formato cioè premettendo un prefisso a un aggettivo o un nome (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-parasintetici_(La-grammatica-italiana)/). Il prefisso "in", in questo caso, significa "fare". Incovonare = fare covoni (come ha giustamente scritto @egreg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Il significato di "incovonare" si trova sul supplemento del 2009 al [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI24/GDLI_Supplemento_2009_Pagina_426.jpg), che cita proprio come esempio il primo passaggio di Fenoglio che appare nella domanda:

> **Incovonare**, tr. (*incóvono*). Raccogliere in covoni. – Anche
>   assol. 
>       [...] 
>       = Comp. dal pref.
>   *in-*, con valore illativo, e un denom. da *covone*.